# How to return temporary CLOB instance from stored function in Pl/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

My stored function creates temporary LOB instance using: `Dbms_Lob.CreateTemporary(BUFFER, TRUE, Dbms_Lob.SESSION);` where `BUFFER` is a local `CLOB` variable. After that the function fills `BUFFER` with some data and returns it.

Duration parameter of `Dbms_Lob.CreateTemporary` in my case is `Dbms_Lob.SESSION`, but according to [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1015757):

> **The duration parameter** passed to dbms_lob.createtemporary() **is a hint**.
>   The duration of the new temp LOB is the same as the duration of the
>   locator variable in PL/SQL. For example, in the preceding program
>   block, the program variable a has the duration of the residing frame.
>   Therefore at the end of the block, memory of a will be freed at the
>   end of the function.

So `BUFFER CLOB` may be destroyed by Oracle after leaving the function block. I can see that in some cases, when the BUFFER is more than 32K, I can’t read it’s value returned this way from Java (JDBC) side.

Is there any other way to return temporary CLOB instance from a function?

Comment: Can you convert you function to a procedure and use an IN OUT parameter of type clob?

Comment: @Alen Oblak, actually no, because I have to use this function in SELECT statement.

Comment: Then maybe you can declare a package-level variable and return that from the function.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, using of a package-level variable may change the state of package which is a problem when the function is called from several sessions concurrently.

Comment: why can't you just return a clob?

Comment: Volodymyr, each session gets its own instance of the package variables.

Comment: tbone, you can just return a CLOB in Oracle by casting VARCHAR2 to a CLOB. It means that size of returned CLOB cannot be more than max size of VARCHAR2 (which is ~32K). If you need more size for your CLOB data, you need to create CLOB object in temporary tablespace with using of Dbms_Lob.CreateTemporary.

Comment: Do you only, and consistently, have a problem when the CLOB is more than 32K? If so that sounds like a JDBC problem, or an issue with how you're retrieving the value on the Java end. Maybe adding your Java code might reveal something?

Comment: On Java side clob.getSubString(0, clob.length()) throws:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
        at oracle.sql.CLOB.getSubString(CLOB.java:236)

while clob.length() returns actual length of my clob.

Comment: Alex, reading the clob with using of clob.getCharacterStream().read() works as expected. So the problem is with JDBC namely implementation of oracle.sql.CLOB.getSubString. Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment you said:

> `clob.getSubString(0, clob.length())` throws: `java.sql.SQLException:
>   Invalid argument(s) in call at
>   oracle.sql.CLOB.getSubString(CLOB.java:236)` while `clob.length()`
>   returns actual length of my clob

The documentation of [`getSubString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Clob.html#getSubString%28long,%20int%29) states that:

> pos - the first character of the substring to be extracted. The first character is at position 1.

With a simple function to generate and return a CLOB, I can retrieve it over JDBC (`ojdbc5` or `ojdbc6`) with no problems, either with `getCLOB()` or `getString()`. But if I try to assign the `Oracle.sql.CLOB` retrieved with `getCLOB` to a `String` using

```
String x = getSubString(0, clob.length());
```

then I also get the `Invalid argument(s) in call` error. Just changing that to:

```
String x = getSubString(1, clob.length());
```

works. So it seems to have nothing to do with the temporary allocation in the function, or the CLOB size. I don't understand why you didn't have a problem with smaller CLOBs - maybe your logic just didn't hit this if they were small?

In the meantime you've worked around this with `clob.getCharacterStream().read()`, so this may be a bit irrelevant now.

Answer (score 3):

I created the function to return a clob, with random generated data, lenght is 200k characters.

```
create function f_clob
return clob is
   l_clob      CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB;
   l_len       BINARY_INTEGER;
   l_content   VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, TRUE);
   dbms_lob.open(l_clob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
   --
   for i in 1..100
   loop
      l_content := dbms_random.string('A', 2000);
      l_len := length(l_content);
      dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, l_len, l_content);
   end loop;
   dbms_lob.close(l_clob);
   --
   return l_clob;
end f_clob;
```

Then I call the function:

```
select to_char(substr(f_clob, 1, 200)) clob_chunk
from  (
   select 1
   from dual
   union
   select 2
   from dual)
```

And I always get data out as a result. I wonder why your function isn't returning data.

Comment: I did the something similar and always get the full CLOB from a Java program too (using ojdbc5 or ojdbc6 from the 11gR2 instant client).

Comment: After investigation it looks like the problem is related to the implementation of oracle.sql.CLOB.getSubString, in case when length of the clob is more than ~32K. clob.getCharacterStream().read() works as expected.