# How could i send more than 32,767bytes?

Tags: sql, c, plsql

I am using a plsql function, I defined a variable as `xx varchar2(32767)`.

I declared a cursor then starts a `for` loop. It concatenate data to `xx` when i return data from the function. **But** I got an error  "character buffer is too small" . Is it possible to retrieve pending data from a cursor,then anybody can explain with detailed example?

declare
print varchar2(32767);

cursor test select custcode,name,address from custmstr where department = 2;

begin

for i in test loop
      print:= print || tespackage.print("here some package contents);
   end loop;

end;
return print;

Comment: please show us what you have tried (in source code) stripped to the bare minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in title, use CLOB. CLOB is capable of handling 2,147,483,647 characters.
Although your requirements are not clear but based on situation you are in, you may

1. Return the cursor itself.
2. Return a CLOB.

Refer to function given by "Alen Oblak" at [How to return temporary CLOB instance from stored function in Pl/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586253/how-to-return-temporary-clob-instance-from-stored-function-in-pl-sql)

Comment: WHAT ABOUT DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR?

Comment: Yes! Please make use of refcursor.